# Cypress: Change baseUrl with bitbucket pipeline (command line)

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, cypress, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

we are using Cypress and Bitbucket pipelines. We have several development environments and I want to change the baseurl dynamically depending on which branch I select via Bitbucket pipelines.

the script for running the Cypress commands in Bitbucket pipelines looks like this:

```
script:
          - ./hybris-url-mapping.sh $CYPRESS_BASE_URL
          - cd /working
          - npx cypress run  --env baseUrl=$CYPRESS_BASE_URL
```

the script (`./hybris-url-mapping.sh`) which should change the URL based on the selected branch looks like this

```
if [[ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == 'develop' ]]; then CYPRESS_BASE_URL="develop_url" ; fi
if [[ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == 'staging' ]]; then CYPRESS_BASE_URL="staging_url" ; fi
if [[ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == 'staging2' ]]; then CYPRESS_BASE_URL="staging2_url" ; fi
if [[ $BITBUCKET_BRANCH == 'release' ]]; then CYPRESS_BASE_URL="prod_url" ; fi
echo $CYPRESS_BASE_URL
```

now we come to the problem. Unfortunately it does not work. At least in `echo $CYPRESS_BASE_URL` the correct URL is returned based on the branch but it is not set as `baseUrl` in the commandline `npx cypress run --env baseUrl=$CYPRESS_BASE_URL`. There the url in the `cypress.json` is always used:

```
{
  "baseUrl": "local_url"
}
```

i have tried `npx cypress run --env baseUrl=$CYPRESS_BASE_URL` and
`npx cypress run --config baseUrl=$CYPRESS_BASE_URL` but neither works.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: fixed it myself with `export CYPRESS_BASE_URL=$(./hybris-url-mapping.sh)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the variable `CYPRESS_BASE_URL` in a different shell, so when `hybris-url-mapping.sh` exits, it's not exported to the parent shell. It's a security feature, and it can't be changed.

The only way is to echo it and perform command substitution:

```
$ CYPRESS_BASE_URL=$(./hybris-url-mapping.sh)
```

or:

```
$ CYPRESS_BASE_URL=`./hybris-url-mapping.sh`
```

After this line, you will have whatever you echoed in `hybris-url-mapping.sh` in `CYPRESS_BASE_URL`.

Comment: Should the line code be in the Bitbucket pipeline script or in the `hybris-url-mapping.sh` file?

Comment: @pontilicious: in the Bitbucket pipeline script.

Comment: dont work. + $CYPRESS_BASE_URL=$(./hybris-url-mapping.sh)
bash: =https://staging_url/: No such file or directory

Comment: script:
          - ./hybris-url-mapping.sh $CYPRESS_BASE_URL
          - $ CYPRESS_BASE_URL=$(./hybris-url-mapping.sh)
          - cd /working
          - npx cypress run  --env baseUrl=$CYPRESS_BASE_URL

Comment: `No such file or directory` can't really be more explicit. It doesn't know the file. `./` means "search in the current directory", obviously `hybris-url-mapping.sh` can't be found there. I recommend reading more about shell and/or bash instead of copy pasting things from the Internet. A bit about command substitution could be found here https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Command_substitution

Comment: i think it's a misunderstanding! your command works only it gives an error message that makes no sense in my eyes. Your command is executed directly after the `./hybris-url-mapping.sh` and that works too. So I don't understand why your command gives out this error message. It is all in the same directory!
`bash: =CORRECT_URL_FROM_SCRIPT: No such file or directory.` 
According to your command it doesn't have to search for a file or directory, because it should only pass the variable.

Comment: Open bash on your laptop and experiment. It makes no sense to paste something into a pipeline if it doesn't work locally. But it's easier to debug it locally. I can only repeat:  if your script in `hybris-url-mapping.sh` echoes a value, you catch the value by command substitution `CYPRESS_BASE_URL=$(./hybris-url-mapping.sh)`, then you can use `$CYPRESS_BASE_URL` in `$ npx cypress run  --env baseUrl=$CYPRESS_BASE_URL`